# Cant deploy the trained model on Azure ML service

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-deployment, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk, azure-ml-pipelines

Unable to deploy the trained model using Azure Machine Learning SDK v2

I have created and trained the model whose directory looks something like this -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYRpp.png)

The main model script is 'OpenTag2018' and that script is importing other scripts from the subfolder.

I have also created the sore.py that runs when the model is being deployed.

```
import logging
import os
import json
import mlflow
from io import StringIO
from mlflow.pyfunc.scoring_server import infer_and_parse_json_input, predictions_to_json
import sys
from time import strftime, localtime
from collections import Counter
from config import opt
from pytorch_transformers import BertTokenizer
import random
import numpy as np 
import torch 
from tqdm import tqdm

def init():
    global model
    # "model" is the path of the mlflow artifacts when the model was registered. For automl
    # models, this is generally "mlflow-model".
    model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv("AZUREML_MODEL_DIR"), "use-case1-model")
    model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_path)
    logging.info("Init complete")


def run(raw_data):
    data = json.loads(raw_data)
    title = data["title"]
    att = data["attributes"]

    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    def is_english_char(cp):
        """Checks whether CP is the codepoint of an English character."""
        if ((cp >= 0x0041 and cp <= 0x005A) or  # uppercase A-Z
            (cp >= 0x0061 and cp <= 0x007A) or  # lowercase a-z
            (cp >= 0x00C0 and cp <= 0x00FF) or  # Latin-1 Supplement
            (cp >= 0x0100 and cp <= 0x017F) or  # Latin Extended-A
            (cp >= 0x0180 and cp <= 0x024F) or  # Latin Extended-B
            (cp >= 0x1E00 and cp <= 0x1EFF) or  # Latin Extended Additional
            (cp >= 0x2C60 and cp <= 0x2C7F) or  # Latin Extended-C
            (cp >= 0xA720 and cp <= 0xA7FF) or  # Latin Extended-D
            (cp >= 0xAB30 and cp <= 0xAB6F) or  # Latin Extended-E
            (cp >= 0xFB00 and cp <= 0xFB06)):  # Alphabetic Presentation Forms
            return True

        return False

    max_len = 40
    def X_padding(ids):
        if len(ids) >= max_len:  
            return ids[:max_len]
        ids.extend([0]*(max_len-len(ids))) 
        return ids

    tag_max_len = 6
    def tag_padding(ids):
        if len(ids) >= tag_max_len: 
            return ids[:tag_max_len]
        ids.extend([0]*(tag_max_len-len(ids))) 
        return ids


    def nobert4token(tokenizer, title, attribute):

     def get_char(sent):
        tmp = []
        s = ''
        for char in sent.strip():
            if char.strip():
                cp = ord(char)
                if is_english_char(cp):
                    if s:
                        tmp.append(s)
                    tmp.append(char)
                    s = ''
                else:
                    s += char
            elif s:
                tmp.append(s)
                s = ''
        if s:
            tmp.append(s)
        return tmp

        title_list = get_char(title)
        attribute_list = get_char(attribute)
        print(title_list)



        title_list = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(title_list)
        attribute_list = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(attribute_list)
        print(title_list)

        return title_list, attribute_list



    t , a = nobert4token(tokenizer, title.lower(), att[0])

    x = X_padding(t)
    y = tag_padding(a)

    tensor_a = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.int32)
    tensor_a = torch.unsqueeze(tensor_a, dim=0).to('cuda')

    tensor_t = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.int32)
    tensor_t = torch.unsqueeze(tensor_t, dim=0).to('cuda')

    output = model.predict([tensor_t,tensor_a])

    predict_list = output.tolist()[0]

    for i in range(len(predict_list)):
                start_p, end_p= 0,0
                for index,value in enumerate(predict_list[i]):
                    if value == 1:
                        start_p = index
                        j = index
                        while(predict_list[i][j]!=3):
                            j = j + 1
                            end_p = j
                preds = (tensor_t[i][start_p : end_p])
                words_p = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens([i.item() for i in preds.cpu() if i.item()>0])
    return ' '.join(words_p)
```

This is how my function calls look like -

```
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.ai.ml.entities import (
    ManagedOnlineEndpoint,
    ManagedOnlineDeployment,
    Model,
    CodeConfiguration,
    Environment,
)
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

# picking the model to deploy. Here we use the latest version of our registered model
model = ml_client.models.get(name="use-case1-model", version=latest_model_version)


# create an online deployment.
red_deployment = ManagedOnlineDeployment(
    name="blue",
    endpoint_name=online_endpoint_name,
    model=model,
    code_configuration=CodeConfiguration(
        code="./dependencies",
        scoring_script="score.py"
    ),
    environment=env,
    instance_type="Standard_F4s_v2",
    instance_count=1,
)

red_deployment_results = ml_client.online_deployments.begin_create_or_update(
    red_deployment
).result()

print(
    f"Deployment {red_deployment_results.name} provisioning state: {red_deployment_results.provisioning_state}"
)
```

This is how I saved the model using mlflow-

```
    # Registering the model to the workspace
    mlflow.pytorch.log_model(
        pytorch_model= model,
        registered_model_name="use-case1-model",
        artifact_path="use-case1-model",
        input_example=df[['Title', 'Attributes']],
        conda_env=os.path.join("./dependencies", "conda.yaml")
    )

    # Saving the model to a file
    mlflow.pytorch.save_model(
        pytorch_model= model,
        conda_env=os.path.join("./dependencies", "conda.yaml"),
        input_example=df[['Title', 'Attributes']],
        path=os.path.join(args.model, "use-case1-model")
    )
```

My Environment file -

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pip=22.1.2
  - numpy=1.21.2
  - scikit-learn=0.24.2
  - scipy=1.7.1
  - 'pandas>=1.1,<1.2'
  - pytorch=1.10.0
  - pip:
      - 'inference-schema[numpy-support]==1.5.0'
      - xlrd==2.0.1
      - mlflow== 1.26.1
      - azureml-mlflow==1.42.0
      - tqdm==4.63.0
      - pytorch-transformers==1.2.0
      - pytorch-lightning==2.0.2
      - seqeval==1.2.2
      - azureml-inference-server-http==0.8.0
name: model-env
```

And lastly deployment logs shows this:

```
Instance status:
SystemSetup: Succeeded
UserContainerImagePull: Succeeded
ModelDownload: Succeeded
UserContainerStart: InProgress

Container events:
Kind: Pod, Name: Pulling, Type: Normal, Time: 2023-05-23T01:17:31.726303Z, Message: Start pulling container image
Kind: Pod, Name: Downloading, Type: Normal, Time: 2023-05-23T01:17:32.697829Z, Message: Start downloading models
Kind: Pod, Name: Pulled, Type: Normal, Time: 2023-05-23T01:20:06.535632Z, Message: Container image is pulled successfully
Kind: Pod, Name: Downloaded, Type: Normal, Time: 2023-05-23T01:20:06.535632Z, Message: Models are downloaded successfully
Kind: Pod, Name: Created, Type: Normal, Time: 2023-05-23T01:20:06.691742Z, Message: Created container inference-server
Kind: Pod, Name: Started, Type: Normal, Time: 2023-05-23T01:20:06.755508Z, Message: Started container inference-server

Container logs:
2023-05-23T01:20:06,767937802+00:00 - rsyslog/run 
2023-05-23T01:20:06,772188056+00:00 - gunicorn/run 
2023-05-23T01:20:06,773563973+00:00 - nginx/run 
2023-05-23T01:20:06,774047779+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:06,775608299+00:00 | gunicorn/run | ###############################################
2023-05-23T01:20:06,777286120+00:00 | gunicorn/run | AzureML Container Runtime Information
2023-05-23T01:20:06,779026742+00:00 | gunicorn/run | ###############################################
2023-05-23T01:20:06,780637662+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:06,782440485+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:06,786468236+00:00 | gunicorn/run | AzureML image information: openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04, Materializaton Build:20230509.v1
2023-05-23T01:20:06,788041356+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:06,789705877+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:06,791375398+00:00 | gunicorn/run | PATH environment variable: /azureml-envs/azureml_d587e0800be72e17d773ddca63762cd1/bin:/opt/miniconda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
2023-05-23T01:20:06,793025919+00:00 | gunicorn/run | PYTHONPATH environment variable: 
2023-05-23T01:20:06,794927543+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:07,287148945+00:00 | gunicorn/run | CONDAPATH environment variable: /opt/miniconda

# conda environments:
#
                      *  /azureml-envs/azureml_d587e0800be72e17d773ddca63762cd1
base                     /opt/miniconda

2023-05-23T01:20:08,175873674+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:08,177405680+00:00 | gunicorn/run | Pip Dependencies (before dynamic installation)

adal==1.2.7
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
alembic==1.11.1
argcomplete==2.1.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==23.1.0
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.22.1
azure-graphrbac==0.61.1
azure-identity==1.13.0
azure-mgmt-authorization==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry==9.1.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.3.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault==9.3.0
azure-mgmt-resource==21.0.0
azure-mgmt-storage==20.0.0
azureml-core==1.42.0.post1
azureml-inference-server-http==0.8.0
azureml-mlflow==1.42.0
backports.tempfile==1.0
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
bcrypt==4.0.1
boto3==1.26.138
botocore==1.29.138
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi==2023.5.7
cffi @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/cffi_1671179356964/work
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
cloudpickle==2.2.1
cmake==3.26.3
contextlib2==21.6.0
cryptography==36.0.2
databricks-cli==0.17.7
docker==5.0.3
entrypoints==0.4
filelock==3.12.0
Flask==2.2.5
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
frozenlist==1.3.3
fsspec==2023.5.0
future @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/future_1673596611778/work
gitdb==4.0.10
GitPython==3.1.31
google-api-core==2.11.0
google-auth==2.18.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.59.0
greenlet==2.0.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.6.0
importlib-resources==5.12.0
inference-schema==1.5
isodate==0.6.1
itsdangerous==2.1.2
jeepney==0.8.0
Jinja2==3.1.2
jmespath==1.0.0
joblib @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/joblib_1663332044897/work
jsonpickle==2.2.0
knack==0.9.0
lightning-utilities==0.8.0
lit==16.0.5
Mako==1.2.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
mlflow==1.26.1
mlflow-skinny==2.3.2
mpmath==1.3.0
msal==1.22.0
msal-extensions==1.0.0
msrest==0.6.21
msrestazure==0.6.4
multidict==6.0.4
ndg-httpsclient==0.5.1
networkx==3.1
numpy @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/numpy_1629092056723/work
nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11==11.7.101
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96
nvidia-cufft-cu11==10.9.0.58
nvidia-curand-cu11==10.2.10.91
nvidia-cusolver-cu11==11.4.0.1
nvidia-cusparse-cu11==11.7.4.91
nvidia-nccl-cu11==2.14.3
nvidia-nvtx-cu11==11.7.91
oauthlib==3.2.2
opencensus==0.11.2
opencensus-context==0.1.3
opencensus-ext-azure==1.1.9
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.1.5
paramiko==2.12.0
pathspec==0.11.1
pkginfo==1.9.6
portalocker==2.7.0
prometheus-client==0.16.0
prometheus-flask-exporter==0.22.4
protobuf==4.23.1
psutil==5.9.5
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pycparser @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pycparser_1636257122734/work
pydantic==1.10.7
Pygments==2.15.1
PyJWT==2.7.0
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/python-dateutil_1626286286081/work
pytorch-lightning==2.0.2
pytorch-transformers==1.2.0
pytz @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pytz_1680088766131/work
PyYAML==6.0
querystring-parser==1.2.4
regex==2023.5.5
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
s3transfer==0.6.1
sacremoses==0.0.53
scikit-learn @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/scikit-learn_1630910537183/work
scipy @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/scipy_1628206382406/work
SecretStorage==3.3.3
sentencepiece==0.1.99
seqeval==1.2.2
six @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/six_1620240208055/work
smmap==5.0.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.15
sqlparse==0.4.4
sympy==1.12
tabulate==0.9.0
threadpoolctl @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/threadpoolctl_1643647933166/work
torch==2.0.1
torchmetrics==0.11.4
tqdm==4.63.0
triton==2.0.0
typing_extensions @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/typing_extensions_1678559861143/work
urllib3==1.26.9
websocket-client==1.5.2
Werkzeug==2.3.4
wrapt==1.12.1
xlrd==2.0.1
yarl==1.9.2
zipp==3.15.0

2023-05-23T01:20:08,836735094+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:08,838657201+00:00 | gunicorn/run | ###############################################
2023-05-23T01:20:08,840420508+00:00 | gunicorn/run | Checking if the Python package azureml-inference-server-http is installed
2023-05-23T01:20:08,842133215+00:00 | gunicorn/run | ###############################################
2023-05-23T01:20:08,843869922+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:09,830826034+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:09,832438140+00:00 | gunicorn/run | ###############################################
2023-05-23T01:20:09,833918246+00:00 | gunicorn/run | AzureML Inference Server
2023-05-23T01:20:09,835327752+00:00 | gunicorn/run | ###############################################
2023-05-23T01:20:09,836711457+00:00 | gunicorn/run | 
2023-05-23T01:20:10,875997877+00:00 | gunicorn/run | Starting AzureML Inference Server HTTP.
2023-05-23 01:20:11,049 I [10] azmlinfsrv - Loaded logging config from /azureml-envs/azureml_d587e0800be72e17d773ddca63762cd1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml_inference_server_http/logging.json
2023-05-23 01:20:11,143 I [10] gunicorn.error - Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2023-05-23 01:20:11,144 I [10] gunicorn.error - Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:31311 (10)
2023-05-23 01:20:11,144 I [10] gunicorn.error - Using worker: sync
2023-05-23 01:20:11,146 I [70] gunicorn.error - Booting worker with pid: 70

Azure ML Inferencing HTTP server v0.8.0


Server Settings
---------------
Entry Script Name: /var/azureml-app/dependencies/score.py
Model Directory: /var/azureml-app/azureml-models/use-case1-model/3
Worker Count: 1
Worker Timeout (seconds): 300
Server Port: 31311
Application Insights Enabled: false
Application Insights Key: None
Inferencing HTTP server version: azmlinfsrv/0.8.0
CORS for the specified origins: None


Server Routes
---------------
Liveness Probe: GET   127.0.0.1:31311/
Score:          POST  127.0.0.1:31311/score

Initializing logger
2023-05-23 01:20:11,423 I [70] azmlinfsrv - Starting up app insights client
2023-05-23 01:20:12,970 E [70] azmlinfsrv - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d587e0800be72e17d773ddca63762cd1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml_inference_server_http/server/user_script.py", line 74, in load_script
    main_module_spec.loader.exec_module(user_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/azureml-app/dependencies/score.py", line 10, in <module>
    from config import opt
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d587e0800be72e17d773ddca63762cd1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml_inference_server_http/server/config.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..constants import DEFAULT_APP_ROOT
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d587e0800be72e17d773ddca63762cd1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml_inference_server_http/server/aml_blueprint.py", line 88, in setup
    self.user_script.load_script(config.app_root)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d587e0800be72e17d773ddca63762cd1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml_inference_server_http/server/user_script.py", line 76, in load_script
    raise UserScriptImportException(ex) from ex
azureml_inference_server_http.server.user_script.UserScriptImportException: Failed to import user script because it raised an unhandled exception

2023-05-23 01:20:12,970 I [70] gunicorn.error - Worker exiting (pid: 70)
2023-05-23 01:20:13,162 I [10] gunicorn.error - Shutting down: Master
2023-05-23 01:20:13,163 I [10] gunicorn.error - Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Azure ML Inferencing HTTP server v0.8.0


Server Settings
---------------
Entry Script Name: /var/azureml-app/dependencies/score.py
Model Directory: /var/azureml-app/azureml-models/use-case1-model/3
Worker Count: 1
Worker Timeout (seconds): 300
Server Port: 31311
Application Insights Enabled: false
Application Insights Key: None
Inferencing HTTP server version: azmlinfsrv/0.8.0
CORS for the specified origins: None


Server Routes
---------------
Liveness Probe: GET   127.0.0.1:31311/
Score:          POST  127.0.0.1:31311/score

2023-05-23T01:20:13,206072314+00:00 - gunicorn/finish 3 0
2023-05-23T01:20:13,207564233+00:00 - Exit code 3 is not normal. Killing image.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Deployment logs provided, you are getting

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
with
File "/var/azureml-app/dependencies/score.py", line 10, in <module>
from config import opt
File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d587e0800be72e17d773ddca63762cd1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml_inference_server_http/server/config.py", line 8, in <module>
from ..constants import DEFAULT_APP_ROOT
```

This means that the Python interpreter is unable to find the module that you are trying to import. In this case, you are trying to import the `opt` variable from the `config` module.

If you want to access DEFAULT_APP_ROOT, you can directly import this:

```
from azureml_inference_server_http.server import config
from azureml_inference_server_http.constants import DEFAULT_APP_ROOT
```

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) for more details on **relative import error**.